# Processing Pipeline using Spark SQL- jobs, stages and DAG sizes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a processing pipeline that is built using Spark SQL. The objective is to read data from Hive in the first step and apply a series of functional operations (using Spark SQL) in order to achieve the functional output. Now, these operations are quite in number (more than 100), which means I am running around 50 to 60 spark sql queries in a single pipeline. While the application completes successfully without any issues, my focus area has shifted to optimizing the overall process. I have been able to speed up the executions using spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, changing the executor memory and reducing the size of the spark.memory.fraction from default 0.6 to 0.2. I got great benefits by doing all these changes and the over all execution time reduced from 20-25 mins to around 10 mins. Data volume is around 100k rows (source side).

The observations that I have from the Cluster are:
-The number of jobs triggered as apart of application id are 235. 
-The total number of stages across all the jobs created are around 600.
-8 executors are used in a two node cluster (64 GB RAM in total with 10 cores).
-The resource manager UI of Yarn (for an application id) becomes very slow to retrieve the details of jobs/stages.

In one of the videos of Spark tuning, I heard that we should try to reduce the number of stages to a bare minimum, also DAG size should be smaller. What are the guidelines to do this. How to find the number of shuffles that are happening (my SQLs have many joins and group by clauses).

I would like to have suggestions on the above scenario of what possible things I can do in order to improvise the performance and handle the data skews in the SQL queries that are JOIN/GROUP_BY heavy.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that data evenly distributed across all partitions

Comment: Ok, so, you mean to say that while data is being stored in Hive, someone has to ensure that it is evenly distributed across all the datanodes (nodes of cluster). This will automatically help to spread data uniformly in memory once spark pulls it in memory from each node?  One more thing, what is the most followed method to find whether data is uniformly present in Hive or not?

Comment: If you have skewed data, some partitions have  more data compared to other,  you can do **bucketing** in that particular partition, although  to get the optimum performance it depends on  your query if it has where clause, Don't know how to check  data uniformity in the hive(hive query can help), in spark you can get more clear picture by observing DAG